# Python - How to load a config file installed from a PyPI package?

Tags: python, config, pypi

I have a Python library (I'm the creator of) that installs to the folders below:

```
/Users/my_user/some_directory/venv/config/config.json
/Users/my_user/some_directory/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/my_package_module/* (rest of the files)
```

However, when I'm running the library, it is unable to locate the config.json file. Which of the following is the proper approach here:

1. Reconfigure the `config` folder to be installed under the `my_package_module` directory?
2. Have the library reference the `config` folder as is?

If taking the 2nd approach, how do I ensure that all users (Windows, Mac, Linux, AWS, etc) are all referring to the `config` that was installed during `pip install <my_package_module>`?

I'm currently using `with open(os.path.join(sys.prefix, "config/config.json")) as json_data_file` in the package but I don't think this works on all scenarios.

Comment: Why have a json file at all? You could store the parsed Python object as a variable in a Python module

Comment: Technically I could, but that is a huge JSON blob which I'd like to avoid polluting my main code

Comment: What difference does it make if it’s in a .json file or a .py file? A json file is still “polluting” your codebase but you’re just hiding it in a “config” file

Comment: Good call, I am going to convert it into a Python module for simplicity